# A single word for a person who couldn't fulfill his/her dream

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a person who couldn't fulfill his dream in life called? I'm talking about someone who wanted to become something that he couldn't become. I would like a single word with this exact meaning, please.

Example:

> I loved someone but I couldn't get her because she got married to someone else for her family reason.

Comment: Did he achieve anything at all? Sometimes you may not fulfill your dreams but you still enjoyed an excellent life.

Comment: You could try searching an online thesaurus for "dreamer", to see if anything there helps. Here's one: (http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/dreamer).

Comment: You could say that someone who became an accountant is a *frustrated acrobat*. That means he would love to have been an acrobat, but as he suffered from vertigo he had to settle for doing numerical gymnastics with people's tax returns.

Comment: Or, someone who is an accountant could be a "failed acrobat", if they weren't actually good at being an acrobat.

Comment: I mean someone who couldn't attain his dreams due to some complications in life for eg.I loved someone but I couldn't get her because she get married to someone else for her family reason. So in a positive way the perosn would be called ?

Comment: "Cosmically jinxed"?  "Screwed from the get-go"?  "Born under a bad sign?" (courtesy of "Cream") Also, there's something about an albatross that I can't quite remember...

Comment: Or someone who had a God-given gift for acrobatics, may have been too scared, not bold enough, to pursue her gift, and hence lived life on the ground rather than the high wire.

Comment: I have heard people say "He led a **sedentary** life".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word that most aptly describes someone unfulfilled in achieving a goal or unable to live up to their full potential is "manque." However, your example indicates love and loss. You could say this person is a "failed romantic." Such a person's love would usually be termed "unrequited." They could be an "unrequited lover." Summarizing this in one word, one could say that the person was "unrewarded" or "unfulfilled."

> **manque**
> man·qué (mäN-kā′) adjective  –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/manque)
>
> Unfulfilled or frustrated in the realization of one's ambitions or capabilities: *an artist manqué.*

Comment: any citation of reference to support your answer?

Comment: [manqué](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/manque)
adj. Unfulfilled or frustrated in the realization of one's ambitions or capabilities: an artist manqué.
[unrequited](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unrequited)
1. not returned or reciprocated: unrequited love.
2. not avenged or retaliated: an unrequited wrong.
3. not repaid or satisfied. 
[unfulfilled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unfulfilled)
unfulfilled - of persons; marked by failure to realize full potentialities; "unfulfilled and uneasy men"; "unrealized dreams and ambitions"

Comment: Just to make it clear to the OP (you already mentioned an example to this effect), the adjective _manqué_ is usually used postpositionally.

Comment: The definitions of "manqué" unrequited and unfulfilled, supporting your answer - which should also include source citations (in plain text) - will better serve the OP and other users (in addition to yourself, in terms of positive votes) if they are edited into the body of your answer.

Comment: Yeah, and actually **using** this will send everyone off to find a dictionary because it's so obscure.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I have to agree with Cajita.  The word manque is too obscure for normal usage.

Comment: Can you use it in a sentence in the context of the question? I don't see how it would work. (Also, you need the accent on the é, otherwise it is a different word.)

Answer (score 7):

As Catija said, more context would help, but for now one of the meanings of the word **[unfulfilled](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unfulfilled)** might fit the bill:

> Not having fully utilized or exploited one’s abilities or character:
>
> *I was restless and unfulfilled* (ODO)

---

EDIT (from OP's comments): The word unfulfilled is either **neutral or negative**, depending on the context:

> Because of the circumstances that hindered me and the dreams I had to leave behind, I felt unfulfilled for my whole life.

It doesn't have to mean that you want to say something bad (negative) about yourself, but it it does say that you **feel** bad (close to unhappy).

> *It is doubtful that fulfillment is an independent good, although feeling fulfilled is pleasant and feeling unfulfilled unpleasant.*

From: [Self-Interest: Volume 14, Part 1](https://books.google.rs/books?id=gMIFQSDlp8wC&pg=PA220&dq=%22feeling+unfulfilled%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22feeling%20unfulfilled%22&f=false) by Ellen Frankel Paul, Fred D. Miller, Jr, Jeffrey Paul, Cambridge University Press, 1997

On the other hand, it might be used to say something negative of a person (especially when used attributively):

> *He was a deeply depressed, inhibited, bitter, and unfulfilled person.*

from: [Excellent Sheep: The Miseducation of the American Elite and the Way to a Meaningful Life](https://books.google.rs/books?id=1iRyCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA160&dq=%22unfulfilled+person%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22unfulfilled%20person%22&f=false) by William Deresiewicz, Simon and Schuster, 2015

It is difficult to find a word with positive connotations, that would describe a person who hasn't fulfilled a dream as such (you could add even more context such as: *despite the fact that his dream remained unfulfilled he kept fighting/dreaming* etc - but then the word would depend on the added context).

A word that would be **neutral** regarding someone's personality (but still describing their feelings as sad) would be:

**[regretful](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/regretful)**:

> Feeling or showing regret (ODO)
>
> ---
>
> *I felt love for Bill, but I was regretful that I hadn't gotten a degree, and resentful that I was expected to carry the entire domestic load.*

Example from: [Duchess of Palms: A Memoir](https://books.google.rs/books?id=Q9aHbEm6ub0C&pg=PA30&dq=%22was+regretful%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22was%20regretful%22&f=false) by Nadine Eckhardt, University of Texas Press, 2012

Answer (score 6):

Thwarted

His dreams were thwarted.

Merriam-Webster definition of thwart: "to oppose successfully: defeat the hopes or aspirations of

Answer (score 5):

I would say "**[unactualized](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20actualized)**", as "actualized" can mean "to fulfill one's potential".

Answer (score 4):

A single noun for the person themselves would be [failure](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/failure).

> a person or thing that proves unsuccessful:
> *He is a failure in his career. The cake is a failure.*

It is a rather negative word though.

Answer (score 2):

From your description I think that the term ***[disillusioned](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disillusioned)*** may describe how that person can feel:

> - having lost faith or trust in something : disappointed that something is not as good, valuable, true, etc., as it had seemed (M-W)

- disillusioned about what he expected form life.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you mean the person was

> frustrated

in their attempts to marry the dream-spouse.

Answer (score 2):

first word that came to mind was "loser" but you may be looking for something like "thwarted"

Answer (score 1):

**Would-be**.  My would-be wife was already engaged to an astronaut.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a single word but avoids negativism:

To ***[come to terms with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+to+terms+with)***

> to start to accept and deal with a difficult situation