# Sadness over culmination/completion

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm just wondering if there is a word that describes the feeling of sadness I'm experiencing having solved a problem I've been working on every day for the past 10 months.

It should accurately describe:

> pain experienced when something comes to a conclusion/end,

or even better:

> pain experienced when something difficult and consuming ends.

Let me know if clarification is necessary.

Comment: Bereavement comes in all shapes and sizes. Good luck with this one.

Comment: Do you mean something like [Post-Camp Depression](http://www.campamerica.co.nz/blog/article/pcd-post-camp-depression)?

Comment: Catharsis came to mind but it's almost the opposite reaction. Could it be described as a form of withdrawal?

Comment: These are all great! HughMeyers: Bereavement seems more related to loss of something, but still a very powerful instance of pain, Yay: PCD does sound like the same area of pain (something you really enjoyed, coming to an end), JesseM: Catharsis sounds sort of the opposite (something you really didn't enjoy, being lifted off your shoulders). Thanks so much!

Comment: @AidanGomez Right. I wasn't answering, just commiserating. I think you've been bereaved of a certain purpose or motivation in your life but the term bereavement is too broad. Anticlimax doesn't quite do it either. You can be satisfied with your solution but still miss the stimulation of the chase. Let-down doesn't hit all the right notes either, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Maybe it’s a form of *postpartum depression*

Comment: ... post-achievement depression (or sweet sadness of accomplishment)

Comment: Actually Jesse, I think it is a form of catharsis, just not the one that is normally talked about.  I've experienced this emotion more times than I can count and never been able to find a word that perfectly suits it.  I think the words that came closest for me were **melancholy** and **introspective** but neither word really captures that sense of, I don't know, almost like being severed from the world around you, like a form of partial death.

Comment: How can solving an almost year long problem be painful? What am I missing?

Comment: Not a single word, but *at loose ends* has exactly this meaning in the US. However, the very similar British *at a loose end* lacks the emotional drama and basically just means you aren't very busy at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, **at loose ends** is a sadness felt when you are suddenly left with nothing to do. (In Britain, the similar *at a loose end* doesn't imply sadness, and generally involves less drama.)

> at loose ends:
>   Not knowing what to do esp. because of some upsetting change.   He was
>   at loose ends when their long-term relationship broke up.   Etymology:
>   based on the idea of a string or rope with ends that
>   are not neatly tied together

Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge University Press 2003.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with hollow.  A problem like that can fill you with purpose.  Once the problem is solved, it can leave you feeling hollow.

Answer (score 0):

Is the person sad because they no longer have something to strive for or because the solution to the problem was disappointing or unsatisfying in some way?

**Disillusionment** is a feeling of disappointment resulting from the discovery that something is not as good as one believed it to be.

I also imagine the feeling would be *empty*, *disappointing*, or *hollow*.

Or perhaps **purposeless**, **aimless**, **goalless** or **directionless**?  The feeling of having to aim or goal or purpose to strive for.  That feeling would be pretty empty/hollow as well and might be closer to what you're looking for.

You might find this question helpful: [a word for a person who never attains a desire or goal](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256027/a-word-for-a-person-who-never-attains-a-desire-or-goal)